# Run 4 threads at same time, if complete to excute 1 thread then excute new thread?

Tags: multithreading

I have 30 tasks.
I want to run 4 threads at a same time to do 4 first tasks.
If any threads completed, i want to excute next thread  and it always has 4 threads at same time

When I completed 28 tasks (7 times), I only do 2 tasks (2 threads)
How to solve it ? i use threading namespace
Thank you

Comment: It would help if you read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned any particular language here, but in case you are using java this is a classic use case of ThreadPoolExecutor.

If you are using some other coding language, you can have your own implementation of simplified ThreadPoolExecutor. Basically:

1. A thread safe list of tasks to be executed
2. 4 threads reading from the queue and executing tasks
3. Implement the termination logic for your threads (you may want to terminate if thread finds that the queue is empty or may be wait for some time and then try again)